# Unique identifier of connected client

Tags: c++, windows, security, tcp, userinfo

I need some help finding out what functions can be used to get as unique information as possible about the connected client. All I know is how to get the client's ip address which can represent several machines, not only the connected client.

Is it possible to request information about the machine's hardware, unique serial number etc?

Let's say I want to ban a user / client on a ip address but I dont want the ban to affect the others on the same ip.

Comment: not possible. you can get only info which client send you by self

Comment: @RbMm 
Can any of that information be used for my example?

Comment: what information ?

Comment: "you can get only info which client send you by self" can any of that info be used to identify a client, except ip address

Comment: but what client send to you ?

Comment: The comments so far are competely incorrect. The client is uniquely identified by its IP address and port. But you can't use that to ban anybody, as it's dynamic. @RbMm

Comment: lets say its a client that doesn't send anything, just connects to socket/tcp without sending/closing

Comment: @user207421 - that ip known is in the question. port nothing give at all. *just connects to socket/tcp without sending/closing* - so you just have **nothing**, except ip address

Comment: @user207421 is it not possible for multiple computers to share the same port on the same ip?

Comment: @Arre - port this only "callback" address. in security this is nothing at all. you want impossible

Comment: @RbMm so how do I get impossible?

Comment: you can not. only ip - that is all what you have in general case